# How do I also get the id of the last column I selected in my SQL Server query?

Tags: php, sql-server

Example database of the table, employees:

```
id      market      firstName
1       1           John
2       2           James
3       1           Sally
4       1           Mary
5       2           Susan
```

If I write the following query,

```
SELECT firstName 
FROM employees 
WHERE market = 1
```

I will get the following array:

```
array("John", "Sally", "Mary")
```

I am using odbc to connect to a sql server and then odbc_fetch_array to retrieve the results. However, I wish to also have the `id` of the last `firstName` pulled, for example:

```
array("John", "Sally", "Mary", 4)
```

I already know how to do this with two queries, but I am wishing to improve performance, how would I do this in one query?

If it matters, I am using odbc to connect to a sql server.

Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be very easy if you use a second query to get that value. Is it posible or does it have to be only one query?

Comment: `SELECT id, firstName FROM employees WHERE market = 1` will not really affect the performance of your query.

Comment: Yes, actually I agree with @StackExchanger

Comment: If you show the actual PHP code that you use to build that array someone will help you with that as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you can't mix datatypes in an array, I'm going to assume it's ok with you if the last id is returned as a string.

In this case, you can use a UNION ALL:

```
SELECT firstName 
FROM employees 
WHERE market = 1
UNION ALL 
SELECT CAST(MAX(id) AS varchar(31))
FROM employees 
WHERE market = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. This statement does not return the id of the last person I pulled, it returns the id of last column in the database. So, in this example, it would have returned array("John", "Sally", "Mary", "5") and I am wanting it to return array("John", "Sally", "Mary", "4").

Comment: Did you include the last `WHERE market=1`?   The results you got should not be possible if you did.

Comment: Actually my real query had a top 200 in it and I forgot to put top 200 a second time. I see that this works. Thank you very much!!